# Can Protractor be installed on Ubuntu OS machine? How will that differ from Windows or OS X machines?

Tags: protractor

I installed protractor on OS X machine and my colleague has Windows 10 machine, We want to install it on our office machine which has Linux server.

My questions are:

1. Does protractor support Linux server platform?
2. Can we access protractor using VPN?
3. Can we save our scripts at common server and call them while execution?
4. Will there be any change in commands and any other process if we test on Linux server.
5. If both of us want to work on protractor at the same time can we access scripts from common server at the same time?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: why do you want to install it to a linux server? is there any specific requirement to install protractor in a server?

Comment: My office machines have only linux severs.